# Guide on using fortran library

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need to use some fortran packages for my work. I searched internet and installed this library along with GSL, as this said to be containing lots f important scientific programs like eigensystems.
https://doku.lrz.de/display/PUBLIC/FGSL+-+A+Fortran+interface+to+the+GNU+Scientific+Library
I am new in the field of using these libraries or some guides. Can someone tell me how to use these libraries? I did not find any searching internet.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is much to general to give a good answer. Can you make your question more specific? Best would be to give us example code showing what you are trying to do and explaining why it is not working. And also if it is specifically eigensystems you are interested in it might be simpler to use LAPACK - google will help you here.

Comment: I understand your point, I know that it is very general. I am actually new in using this sort of stuffs. If you manage to give one example .f90 which uses this that would be enough. I have used blas, lapack routines earlier, but here I cant find any guide type thing like those available for lapack.

Comment: I haven't used it mysefl, but there is a tests directory on the github repository which might help https://github.com/reinh-bader/fgsl/tree/master/tests